# With NavigationLink isActive deprecated, how do I rewrite it to work with in .background()?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm following a course at Codecademy and it's using:

```
  @State var quantityRemaining = Int.random(in: 1...10)
  let itemName: String
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("\(itemName)")
        .font(.title)
        .padding()
      Spacer()
      Image(systemName: "photo")
        .font(.system(size: 200))
        .padding()
      Text("Quantity Remaining: \(quantityRemaining)")
      Spacer()
      Button {
        if quantityRemaining > 0 {
          quantityRemaining -= 1
        }
      } label: {
        Text("Add one to your cart")
      }
      Spacer()
    }
    // .background() runs the view below in the background
    .background(
      // The navigation link is not active until the quantity is 0
      NavigationLink(destination: Text("You bought all the \(itemName)!"),
                     isActive: .constant(quantityRemaining == 0),
                     label: { EmptyView() })
    )
  }
```

The problems I'm having are down where .background() begins with the NavigationLink and using .isActive. .isActive obviously does not work now and is deprecated. I've tried to search and came up with results to use NavigationStack and .navigationDestination but I don't know how to implement it within this context as it is inside of .background() and it doesn't use a NavigationView to change to NavigationStack. It's just a stand-alone NavigationLink.

Can anyone help to rewrite this link properly now that isActive is deprecated?

Thank you.

I tried myself but .navigationDestination only accepts isPresented and I can't figure out how to use the EmptyView and Destination with it.

Comment: See [NavigationLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink)
 and [Migrating NavigationLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types) these links show you how to do it.

Comment: I've looked at that documentation. I don't understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is using `NavigationStack` with a path. Here's a (simplified) snippet of code that modifies code in the original question and behaves exactly as it:

```swift
var body: some View {
  NavigationStack(path: $path) { // 1. Wrap the view with a stack.
  VStack {
    Text("\(itemName)")
      .font(.title)
      .padding()
    Spacer()
    Image(systemName: "photo")
      .font(.system(size: 200))
      .padding()
    Text("Quantity Remaining: \(quantityRemaining)")
    Spacer()
    Button {
      if quantityRemaining > 0 {
        quantityRemaining -= 1
        if quantityRemaining == 0 { // 4. Modify the path, when condition is met.
          path.append("Open next")
        }
      }
    } label: {
      Text("Add one to your cart")
    }
    Spacer()
  }
    .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { // 3. Handle the path changes.
      if $0 == "Open next" {
        Text("You bought all the \(itemName)!")
      }
    }
  }
}

let itemName: String
@State var quantityRemaining = Int.random(in: 1...10)

@State private var path = [String]() // 2. Add a path.
```

(Some explanations are added in the numbered comments.